# Java - JTextArea not shown after putting JscrollBar

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane

I am new to Jframes and I wanted to design a window with a textbox and two buttons. I am able to get this working except for the scrollbar part.
I have written the below piece of code to enable scrollbar to the textarea.

```
private JTextArea outputPane;
outputPane = new JTextArea();
outputPane.setColumns(20);
outputPane.setRows(5);
outputPane.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 18));
outputPane.setBounds(12, 13, 408, 189);
contentPane.add(outputPane);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(outputPane);
jScrollPane1.setBounds(399, 13, 21, 189);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

Now the problem is I am getting a disabled scrollbar on the window but I cannot see my Text Area.

Please help me out with the problem. I even tried using WindowsBuilder but I cannot figure it out.

Detailed explanation with the corrected code will be appreciated as I am still in the learning stage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd start with [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) probably wouldn't hurt

Answer (score 2):

Start by having a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) probably wouldn't hurt

> Now the problem is I am getting a disabled scrollbar on the window but I cannot see my Text Area.

The likely problem is, you are seeing your `JTextArea`, the "disabled" scroll bar is simply because you're using `scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS`, which will always display the scroll bar, even when there is nothing to be scrolled, so it probably looks empty.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        // Swing is not thread safe, so need to get started in the
        // Event Dispatching Thread before we do anything
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // I simply hate the default look and feel                      
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Always better to create an instance of a window
                // to display you content then to extend from one  
                // directly...
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Our main UI, I do it this way so I'm not locked into a single
    // use case and can decide how I want to use the view
    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            // The default layout is a FlowLayout, so we want to change
            // this will allow the main component to occupy the whole
            // available space
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            // Providing "sizing" hints, 10 rows, 20 columns, this is
            // platform independent, so it will size accordingly
            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(10, 20);
            JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ta);
            add(sp);
        }

    }

}
```